# definition for __ THROW __nonnull

Tags: c, string.h

I see the definition of memmove() and memcpy() which both contain the line
**__THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));**
where can I find this defined ?

Comment: That's non-standard. What compiler did you get those headers from?

Comment: `nonnull` is a GCC function attribute (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)). `__nonnull((1, 2))` is a macro that probably expands to `__attribute__((nonnull(1, 2)))` on GCC and to an empty string on other compilers.

Comment: `include/sys/cdefs.h` in uClibc defines those macros.

Comment: Just remove them. They're not needed.

Comment: And they are intended only for internal use in libc, not as public macros. You can tell this by the fact that they start with `__`.

Comment: where can i find the definition for __THROW ?